# Using multiple keytabs in Kerberos JGSS without using JAAS .conf file

Tags: kerberos, jaas, jgss

I want to use multiple keytabs in multiple server threads. I don't want to use JAAS conf file so i implemented my own login configuration in LoginConfiguration class. The getGSSCredentials() function in KerberosLogin class is used to get the Credentials by giving keytab location as parameter.

KerberosLogin -> http://ideone.com/vaip3H
LoginConfiguration -> http://ideone.com/jDqlN0

When i ran only two server threads, first one was able to get the credentials from its keytab ( both the server threads use different service principal ) while second one failed. Somehow using `parms.put("refreshKrb5Config","true");` in LoginConfiguration solved the problem.

I am not able to understand why it's not working without refreshing the configuration and for cases in which there will be several such server threads will it be safe to use. Is there any better way to use multiple keytabs ?

Answer (score -1):

It was due to the way java6 handles login config, it has been fixed in java7.